# How to do a case-insensitive sort of pathlib.Path objects?

Tags: python, pathlib

I'd like to do a case-insensitive sort of [pathlib.Path objects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#concrete-paths) based on their filenames i.e. their `str` representation.

By default, calling sorted() on a list of Path objects will sort them, but is case-sensitive.

Things I've tried:

```
>>> sorted(p, key=str.lower)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: descriptor 'lower' for 'str' objects doesn't apply to a 'PosixPath' object
```

```
>>> sorted(p, key=lambda path: str(path).lower)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'builtin_function_or_method' and 'builtin_function_or_method'
```

It feels like there should be an easy way to do this that I'm missing.

Comment: Try adding a paranthesis to call the function: `lambda path: str(path).lower()`

Comment: @ltay I knew it would be something easy, thank you.

Comment: Notice how the error message you got says that you were trying to compare *a function or method*.

Comment: I didn't quite understand it at first, but given the context it now makes sense. Hopefully going forward I'll be able to better recognize this situation.